# Regular Expression for only one character(*) or other alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a condition in regex, the limit is 8 character and it should accept number, alphabet and `?` and if we entered `*` in field it should give error.

or if we typing `*` in input filed.it should accept only one `*` for whole field, none other than that.

eg: `*` is equivalent to `wer?23w4`

regex is:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9?]{8}/
```

Comment: Missing anchors: `^\*|([a-zA-Z0-9?]{8})$`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the alternation operator (`|`) to specify an either-or condition. In your case:

```
/\*|[a-zA-Z0-9?]{8}/
```

This means to match either:

- A single `*` character, nothing else
- Or, exactly eight characters consisting of lowercase, uppercase, digits, or `?`.

Note, depending on how you are using this in code, you probably need to add the anchors `^` and `$`, to make sure it tests against the entire field:

```
/^(?:\*|[a-zA-Z0-9?]{8})$/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/PkKBsTU-V-qMA3Dq)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 /(\*|[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{8})/g
```

for example

```
"33asdsad".match( /(\*|[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{8})/g);
```

and

```
"*".match( /(\*|[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{8})/g)
```

and

```
"234234?d".match( /(\*|[a-zA-Z0-9\?]{8})/g)
```